# Why ferrite magnets demagnetize easier at lower temperatures than others?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter

I have read [here](https://hsisensing.com/temperature-affect-magnetism/#:%7E:text=Temperature%20affects%20magnetism%20by%20either,faster%20and%20more%20sporadic%20rate.) as an exception to the general case especially ferrite magnets demagnetize easier at lower temperatures and not as temperature rises as usual:

> In addition to the strength of the magnet, the ease at which it can be demagnetized also varies with temperature. Like magnet strength, demagnetization resistance generally decreases with increasing temperature. The one exception is ceramic (ferrite) magnets, which are easier to demagnetize at low temperature and harder to demagnetize at high temperature.

What is the physical reason for this behavior?

Comment: Does this happen below some temperature or generally in low temperatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching, I have found in this link [here](https://www.duramag.com/ceramic-magnets/temperature-effects-on-ceramic-magnets/#:%7E:text=Ceramic%20(Ferrite)%20magnets%20are%20susceptible,performance%20of%20the%20Ceramic%20magnet.), something that is not so known in the general audience about ferrite (ceramic) magnets. Although they have depending the specific material used, a maximum temperature, Curie point at about 450-460 C° they can also demagnetize at low relative temperatures because contrary to ferromagnets their magnetization decreases with the decrease in temperature after a certain low temperature value.

> Unlike Neodymium, Samarium Cobalt, and Alnico, Ceramic magnets have a
> Positive Temperature Coefficient for the Intrinsic Coercive Force
> (Hci)

Specifically look this specifications table here from a manufacturer:

[image: ferrite magnet operating range]

[source](https://www.duramag.com/ceramic-magnets/available-ceramic-magnet-grades/)

The above specifies an operating range not lower than 20C° and this has nothing to do with mechanical strength but with the stable magnetization range  of the ferrite magnet (or else called ferr**i**magnet opposite to ferr**o**magnets). Unfortunately I could not find if there is a critical negative temperature point for ferrite magnets although I believe that it is more likely that they gradually loose their magnetism with lowering temperature after a certain low temperature value and not so abrupt like the critical Curie point which results to a total loss of magnetism and is characteristic of ferromagnets.

Nevertheless it is interesting to know that you possible could demagnetize a ferrite magnet nearly to zero field strength much easier and convenient by putting it to the fridge at say -20 C°  than exposing it to 450C° temperatures and higher which could also physically damage the ferrite magnet.

Answer (score 0):

If the ferrite becomes superconductive it will instantly lose its magnetization.

Comment: I'm skeptical that a superconductive ferrite material exists.  Can you cite a source that describes such a material?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity#:~:text=High%2Dtemperature%20superconductors%20(abbreviated%20high,the%20simplest%20coolants%20in%20cryogenics.

Comment: As far as I know, all materials when becoming superconductors are also turned effectively into diamagnetic.